# Canonically, how much older is Batman than Superman?

Tags: dc, batman, superman

I know this may depend on the continuity, but *generally,* Bruce Wayne has been shown to be a few years older than Clark Kent. This has been portrayed anywhere between 4 to 15, depending on the story, but most usually, Bruce is older. We should also take into account the "sliding time line" which essentially keeps most DC characters at their "canon ages" and simply puts them in different time periods or decades.

Is there a (DC) officially noted age difference between the two?

Comment: @thelethalcarrot doesn't _quiet_ asnwer the question. 1, I wasn't speaking of the _New 52_ world specifically, but okay, that helps.... in _that_ continuity.  I'm speaking here of the _main_ continuity. Batman is generally held to be a few years older than Superman, so I'm trying to find the amount of years, on average.